# Dynamic Column Names with Pivot SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hello all I'm still relatively new to SQL and a search online haven't provided me a solution yet (or its been right in front of me but out of my sphere of knowledge :/). So hoping to try my luck here thanks!

```
Table:   Servers
Columns: ServerUrl               ServerName
Rows:    //server0001/space0/    Telescope1
         //server0001/space1/    Space
         //server0001/space2/    Planet

Table:   Projects
Columns: ServerUrl               Name          Entity     Type
Rows:    //server0001/space0/    Field1        E          T1
         //server0001/space1/    Field2        T          T1
         //server0001/space2/    Field3        E          T3
```

With the stored procedure below I was able to return the data as:

So the ServerUrl gets used as the column names as seen below but I want it to be the ServerName instead. I know its possible to set the columns to be ServerNames but how would I go about doing it dynamically since the ServerUrl may change.

```
--- Returned Data Begin ---
Stored Procedure Results:
Columns: Name    Entity  //server0001/space0/   ...space1  ...space2
Rows:    Field1  E       T1                     NULL       NULL
         Field2  T       NULL                   T2         NULL
         Field3  E       NULL                   NULL       T3     

--- Returned Data End ---
```

***Stored Procedure below used to get Results Above

```
--- STORED PROCEDURE BEGIN ---
DECLARE @Projects varchar(max)
SELECT @ProgramList = COALESCE(@Projects + '], [', '') + ServerURL FROM
Servers ORDER BY ServerURL

SET @ProgramList = CONCAT ('[', @ProgramList + ']')

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
SET @sql = 'select * from ( select P.Name, P.Entity, P.Field, P.ServerUrl 
FROM ProjectFields as P ) as P pivot (min(P.Field) for P.ServerUrl in (' + 
@Projects + ')) as PIV ORDER BY Name'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql1
--- STORED PROCEDURE END ---
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Change the @ProgramList select to be ServerName instead of ServerURL, and change your dynamic statement to be something like `'SELECT * FROM (SELECT P.Name, P.Entity, P.Field, S.ServerName FROM ProjectFields AS P JOIN Servers AS S ON S.ServerURL = P.ServerURL) AS P PIVOT (MIN(Field) FOR ServerName IN (' + @ProgramList + ')) AS PIV ORDER BY PIV.Name;'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your stored procedure looks like it's incomplete or you've changed certain things, but I believe you're looking for something like the following:

```
DECLARE @ProgramList VARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @ProgramList = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(ServerName) FROM [Servers] ORDER BY ServerURL FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '');

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @sql = '
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT P.Name,
           P.Entity,
           P.Field,
           S.ServerName
    FROM ProjectFields AS P
    JOIN [Servers] AS S
        ON S.ServerURL = P.ServerURL
) AS P
PIVOT
(
    MIN(Field) FOR ServerName IN (' + @ProgramList + ')
) AS PIV
ORDER BY PIV.Name;';

--PRINT @sql;
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: Thank you very much ZLK, works like a charm, and yes you're right I changed a few things sorry.